# Problem installing Google Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, google-chrome

I have been using Chrome in 16.04 for some time but since it was having problems I uninstalled it. Now when again I am trying to install it by using the .deb file it's not getting installed.

First, I have the Google chrome stable deb file and when I double click it this happens.

[image]

this page opens in the Software Center.But when I click **Install** nothing happens and I did that many times but of no use.

P.S. I have installed Google Chrome before on 14.04 and 16.04 using this method which I read here but this time it's not working, I don't know why.

One more thing. I am using mobile hotspot for it but its speed is good and it's unlimited to download. So it should not be a problem right?

Comment: The connectiom isn't the problem, try running `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection isn't the problem, try running `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.